# Read eBay price from inside description

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to read an item's price from within its eBay description.

For example, for a fixed-price listing, eBay can write the price near the top of the page with the following HTML:

```html
<span class="notranslate" id="prcIsum" itemprop="price"  style="">$9.95</span>
```

Later on it puts my HTML-based description inside an iframe.

Inside this iframe I've tried to read the price with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" langauge="javascript">
  var txt = parent.document.getElementById("prcIsum").innerHTML;
  document.write(txt);
</script>
```

But nothing ever shows up. Why?

Comment: *Same Origin Policy* explicitly prevents `www.site.com` from accessing a document in an `IFRAME` unless it also comes from `www.site.com`. - consider the implications of putting a bank login page in an frame ...

Comment: Open up the developer console and look at the error message. My guess there will be a [security error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Not just bank logins, but more specifically just on ebay - I would imagine allowing listings to run arbitrary javascript, even if served on the same domain, would be a very bad idea.  What if your listing attempted to click "buy it now"?

Comment: Hmmm..okay. But I don't want to change anything or click on anything. I just want to get hold of the price so I can include it in my shipping calculations. Any bright ideas?

Comment: Don't eBay have an api for this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

It will be way more efficient if you use the Finding API from eBay. You need to sign up as developer and get a token, but it's free of charge. The API output is XML which is really easy to handle. Here is an easy code example for the 'Finding' function:

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/Finding/HowTo/GettingStarted_PHP_XML_XML/GettingStarted_PHP_XML_XML.html

Comment: I don't think that the Finding API will help me, but their GetSingleItem might. However, it seems a very long winded way of getting a number that is on the screen above me and it would expose my EbayAppID to all and sundry - well, the inquisitive at least!

Comment: Also, the documentation I've read for XMLHttpRequest suggests that this won't work across domains either.